# Laravel 4 query builder - not null column not found

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-4

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
    return DB::table('table')->where_not_null('column')->get();
});
```

In Laravel 4 I have the following route, obviously with table and column replaced. I had it in the controller but it wasn't working, so I moved it to a test route.

The error I am getting is:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_not_null' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `table` where `_not_null` = column)
```

https://tower.la.utexas.edu/docs/database/fluent#where

Documentation says:

```
return DB::table('table')->where_null('column')->get();
```

Answer (score 16):

It should be

```
return DB::table('table')->whereNull('column')->get();
```

Or

```
return DB::table('table')->whereNotNull('column')->get();
```

You have used `where_not_null`.This is the [right reference](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects).

Answer (score 1):

See the proper writing for that: http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects

```
DB::table('table')->whereNotNull('column')->get();
```

Answer (score -2):

The documentation states that following the table declaration you should put the query builder information, where_null, where_not_null, where_in.

However that doesn't work. I'm not sure why, it makes no sense, and is frustrating. However, this does work.

```
    return DB::table('user')->whereuserName('not_null')->get();
```

By placing the column name where the documentation says to put the query, and the query where the documentation says to put the column you are able to execute your query. To note, camel case is converted to snake case in the query, so the column has to be named user_name.

I am posting this because I attempted googling it and was not able to find anything.

Comment: I did in the original post.

http://laravel.com/docs/queries

Official docs above, possibly official below? (They are more fleshed out)
https://tower.la.utexas.edu/docs/home

Comment: The documentation you linked to is for Laravel 3.

Comment: @Morgon you're right I was using the incorrect documentation. My error. Sorry for the confusion, I thought it was for 4 and they were similar enough that I thought it was just wrong on the site.